# What is the algorithm behind pairwise2 align in BioPython?

Tags: algorithm, nlp, biopython

The package BioPython allows to compute pairwise local or global alignement, through different functions (align.globalxx, align.localxx, ...).

However, I have not found anywhere the algorithm on which this alignement is based.
The code ([source](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/pairwise2.py), [doc](https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.pairwise2.html)) states: "Pairwise sequence alignment using a dynamic programming algorithm", and that is all.

- Is there a paper on which this implementation is based?
- Is it using a "standard algorithm" and if yes, what is its name?

Edit: This is a question more for citing than for understanding purposes.

Comment: The link you give is to the `.py` source file, not to the documentation.

Comment: Here is the documentation: https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.pairwise2.html

Comment: And there is a list of papers listed here: https://biopython.org/wiki/Documentation

Comment: @Stef yes, and the documentation is automatically extracted from said source file - but I will edit my answer to make it easier to read by linking to the doc.

Comment: Oh, fair enough

Comment: And none of the papers detail the Bio.align module, unless I missed something.

Comment: Not to be snide, but the algorithm is right there in the  Python source. What don't you understand from reading through it?

Comment: @MattDMo If I cite this in a scientific paper, I will need to be able to say "we used biopython's implementation of algorithm BLA, detailed in paper BLI", and at the moment I have neither BLA nor BLI.

Comment: @MattDMo Actually, ty for your comment - I went deeper in the code and found my answer in the docstring of a private function ^^

Comment: @clef I believe there is a way to cite source code (with a Github or other link) in papers. I've never needed to, but I know I've seen it before...

Comment: I guess it depends on the scientific field - this is typically one of these use cases where I actually need the algorithm name, else I will be asked why I have not used stg more standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docstring of a private function in the code indicates that "This is an implementation of the Needleman-Wunsch dynamic programming algorithm as modified by Gotoh, implementing affine gap penalties." (l. 761 of [this code](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/biopython-179/Bio/pairwise2.py#L761-L762)).

Comment: in future consider using the faster and more flexible `Bio.Align` where the algorithms include Needleman-Wunsch, Smith-Waterman, Gotoh, Waterman-Smith-Beyer