# What is the algorithm behind Bio.align in BioPython?

Tags: python, alignment, biopython

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69042028/what-is-the-algorithm-behind-pairwise2-align-in-biopython) but i need different information for citing it in a scientific paper.

For context:
The package [BioPython](https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/index.html) allows to compute pairwise local or global alignement.

However, I have not found anywhere the algorithm on which this alignement is based.

Is there a paper on which this implementation is based?
Is it using a "standard algorithm" and if yes, what is its name?

More specific. I want to know if possible the algorithms behind [Bio.pairwise2](https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.pairwise2.html) and [Bio.Align](https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.Align.html?highlight=bio%20align#module-Bio.Align). A paper would be perfect, but even other information from trusted souces will be fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the algorithm behind pairwise2 align in BioPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69042028/what-is-the-algorithm-behind-pairwise2-align-in-biopython)

Comment: Unfourtunatelly no. I already read that one and the information are not so useful. there's no scientific references nor actual explenation of the algorithm. the only answer refers to a part of the code with a comment that it is not explained very well

Comment: https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec100 : .... Bio.pairwise2 contains essentially the same algorithms as water (local) and needle (global) from the EMBOSS suite (see above) and should return the same results. The pairwise2 module has undergone some optimization regarding speed and memory consumption recently (Biopython versions >1.67) so that for short sequences (global alignments: ~2000 residues, local alignments ~600 residues) it’s faster (or equally fast) to use pairwise2 than calling EMBOSS’ water or needle via the command line tools.

Comment: then use: Madeira F, Pearce M, Tivey ARN, et al. Search and sequence analysis tools services from EMBL-EBI in 2022. Nucleic Acids Research. 2022 Apr:gkac240. DOI: 10.1093/nar/gkac240. PMID: 35412617.  or quote @MattDMod I believe there is a way to cite source code (with a Github or other link) in papers. I've never needed to, but I know I've seen it before...

Comment: https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/d704d1892df77c77acca5a5fb627690464794b9e/Bio/Align/__init__.py#L2547-#L2554